# MySQL COUNT(*) returns empty result set

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently performing great-circle distance calculations on a table in MySQL. The table looks as follows:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| venue_id | lat     | lng     |
+----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | 1.23456 | 2.34567 |
+----------+---------+---------+
| 2        | 1.23456 | 2.34567 |
+----------+---------+---------+
| 3        | 1.23456 | 2.34567 |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

However, when I try to create a `COUNT()` of the results returned, MySQL returns an empty result set.

For example, the following query produces no results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, 
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians('52.97682200')) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                                   Radians(lng) - Radians(-0.02210000)) + 
                              Sin(Radians(52.97682200)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) 
       AS distance 
FROM   wv_venue_locations 
HAVING distance < 5
ORDER  BY distance
```

Yet, running the same query without the `COUNT(*) AS total` field results in the expected 6 results.

Can anyone suggest why this happens, and how I might fix it?

As a post-script to the above, the following works fine:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
       AS 
       total, 
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians(53.18335000)) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                                   Radians(lng) - Radians(-0.29600000)) + 
                              Sin(Radians(53.18335000)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) 
       AS 
       distance 
FROM   wv_venue_locations 
WHERE  lat >= 52.64017900
       AND lat <= 53.72650900
       AND lng >= -0.94998000
       AND lng <= 0.35798000
```

The above correctly outputs:

```
+-------+-------------------+
| total | distance          |
+-------+-------------------+
| 224   | 27.93840157954865 |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Why aren't you groupping your query by any fields?

Comment: @ericpap Why do I need to? Each `venue_id` only exists in the table max once.

Comment: Yeah i think you need to group to be able to count

Comment: @JelleKeizer That's not true. This works fine: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM wv_venues v INNER JOIN wv_venues_types t ON t.venue_id = v.id WHERE t.type_id = :type`

Comment: Try the query without COUNT(*) and see if it gets the results you expect. May help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @DACrosby I already did... Please read the question: `Yet, running the same query without the COUNT(*) AS total field results in the expected 6 results.`

Comment: The query does not make sense to me. COUNT(*) will try to return the total number of row while the distance is the distance from one location to that row location. What is your expected output maybe we try different approach.

Comment: OK. So the query without `COUNT(*)` returns 6 rows. I need a field in the results called `total`, to have a value of `6`.

Comment: The question makes perfect sense to me. Currently Ben has a query that returns a result-set, he simply wants to return the count of that result set. Am I right?

Comment: @George exactly. Other `COUNT(*) AS` casts in the system work fine, just not this one...

Comment: @BenM instead of count(*) use count(subquery) and in the subquery put all your select without the count, you will have then 6 on total

Comment: i know it's only a workaround but first let's fix it

Comment: @George is it the count of the number of rows returned? or a count of the number of distances between one calculation?

Comment: @BenM you could select the id and then call $pdo->rowCount() to return the amount of rows. That's the only way I could think of if the COUNT() function isn't working as you wrote in your original post.

Comment: @MarcoMura `COUNT(subquery)` is invalid syntax..

Comment: @JohnRuddell Sorry, 'SELECT subquery AS total' and in the subquery put all your select without the count, you will have then 6 on total

Comment: @JohnRuddell it should be the number of venues returned by the great-circle distance calc. I don't understand what's so hard?

Comment: @BenM I understand :) just wanted to be sure. can you post a few rows that are relevant for the data? that way I can test it

Comment: @JohnRuddell Here > http://pastebin.com/bt3pg3hb

Comment: @BenM and what output do you expect from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested this and it seems to return what you want. let me know if this isn't correct

```
SELECT SUM(1) as total,
       ( 3959 
        * Acos(  Cos(Radians('52.97682200'))
               * Cos(Radians(lat)) 
               * Cos(Radians(lng) - Radians(-0.02210000)) 
               + Sin(Radians(52.97682200)) 
               * Sin(Radians(lat))
              ) 
       ) AS distance 
FROM   wv_venue_locations 
GROUP BY distance
HAVING distance < 5
ORDER  BY distance
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d1e4f/6)

the main issue is without a group by and an AGGREGATE function it will group all of the rows into one... you need to tell it to separate them out. so I said by distance since you are getting a list of distances by a lat and long.

### EDIT:

if you want one row to be returned showing the total locations within a distance of 5 and the total distance you can do something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(1) as total, SUM(distance) as total_distance, MAX(distance) as furthest_location, MIN(distance) as closest_location
FROM
(   SELECT
        ( 3959 
            * Acos(  Cos(Radians('52.97682200'))
                   * Cos(Radians(lat)) 
                   * Cos(Radians(lng) - Radians(-0.02210000)) 
                   + Sin(Radians(52.97682200)) 
                   * Sin(Radians(lat))
                  ) 
           ) AS distance 
    FROM   wv_venue_locations 
    HAVING distance < 5
    ORDER  BY distance
) t
```

**[SECOND DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d1e4f/11)**

Comment: Thanks John. I'd still like to figure out why the first query returns nothing, and the second query works as expected, though?

Comment: @BenM the second query works because you no longer are restricting the distance... when you say that your calculation has to be a less than 5 but you are ordering in ascending order.. so the aggregate count will group all of the records together but then only return one of the distance calculations... since its ordered it will default to the largest distance which doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

To count rows you can do this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians('52.97682200')) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                                   Radians(lng) - Radians(-0.02210000)) + 
                              Sin(Radians(52.97682200)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) 
       AS distance 
FROM   wv_venue_locations 
HAVING distance < 5
ORDER  BY distance
```

After you have selected needed rows, you can get the count with this single query:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('52.97682200') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( rad' at line 1`

Comment: @BenM remove the comma after found_rows

Comment: Sorry my bad it doesn't need the comma

Comment: Thanks, but how come the second query I posted works fine, but the first doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I figure out why using `HAVING` does not  return any result because `HAVING` will filter row after the grouping. Since you are grouping the whole table, there will be only one row returned. Then, it will be filtered by `HAVING`.

Here is more clearer picture,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, (....) AS distance
FROM wv_venue_locations
```

This query will return one row. Let say the row is

```
total, distance
100, 6.432
```

Then, applying the `HAVING distance < 5`. There is no row that match this condition

---

I don't know if this is what OP want

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(distance)
FROM (
  SELECT 
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians('52.97682200')) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                                   Radians(lng) - Radians(-0.02210000)) + 
                              Sin(Radians(52.97682200)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) 
       AS distance 
   FROM   wv_venue_locations
) AS t
WHERE distance < 5
```

Comment: issue with this explanation is that the distance is not summed up so just one random distance will be pulled out (mysql has the right to select any random row in a grouping)

Comment: @JohnRuddell, the explanation is right. I did not say we have control over what the database will pull out. I just explain the reason why his query has problem and an example. :D

Comment: the issue is the OP is trying to use an aggregate without a group by. here is a count without a group by and still the `having`. it still returns 1 row http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d1e4f/10

Comment: @JohnRuddell, Did I say that using `HAVING` will never return any result. I say `HAVING` does the filtering after the grouping. If after grouping, there is no row that match the condition. It will return nothing. There is one row when group the whole table, sometimes, it will return one row, sometimes it will not.

Comment: I understand. I'm just saying you should clarify that a little more as its misleading. I read your post and its on the right track. I would just include some more details about it

Answer (score -2):

Your `distance < 5` should be in the `WHERE` condition, not in the `HAVING` condition. `HAVING` would be used if you only wanted to show results where the `COUNT()` output meets a certain criteria.

Comment: No dice... `#1054 - Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You can't refer to an alias in a where clause.

Comment: @George You can refer to table alias but not field (or calculation) AS something

Comment: @MarcoMura So.. column alias.

Comment: @MarcoMura distance is a column alias. not a table.

Comment: @JohnRuddell it's a clarification, you can use table name alias inside where condition. He wasn't explaining that =)

Comment: @MarcoMura its obvious you can do that. thats aside the point. the alias distance is referring to a result in the select.. this answer is completely wrong